# Implement a Zend partialLoop() with jQuery nestedSortables

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-view, nested-sortable

This is in fact mainly a Zend question than a jQuery.

I'm trying to implement jQuery nested Sortable http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ with Zend, saving and reading out the exact position of the sortable elements (including their parents). I have now the following code in my partialLoop file which is the main part of my work. It calls itself (recursively) in another partialLoop() method if there are children of an element and looks like the following, which is the partials/_docs-edit-row.phtml itself:

```
<?php
// not really nice to call a db model in a view file, but is there an other way... ?
$docSectionModel = new Model_DocSection();
global $workedthrough, $i;

$childs = $docSectionModel->fetchChildSections($this->id);
if($childs)
    $childs = $childs->toArray();
?>

<?php if(empty($workedthrough) || !in_array($this->id, $workedthrough)) : ?>
<?php $workedthrough[] = $this->id; ?>
<li>
    <div class="handle">
        <input type="hidden" class="section_id" name="section_id[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" class="section_parent_id" name="section_parent_id[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->parent_id; ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="section_title[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->title; ?>" />
        <a href="#" class="open"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-edit closed">
        <textarea name="section_content[<?php echo $i; ?>]"><?php echo $this->content; ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="doc_save" value="Save" />
        <input type="submit" name="remove_doc_section[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Remove this section" />
    </div>

    <?php if($childs) : ?>
        <ol>
            <?php echo $this->partialLoop('partials/_docs-edit-row.phtml', $childs); ?>
        </ol>
    <?php endif; ?>

</li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
```

What I was trying to do here was to create with $i a counter which goes through both loops to get a continous counter because $this->partialCounter would start from the beginning in each new level. So in fact this is my main problem (I defined the $i in the main view file as well as $workthrough which is to look if the item has been gone over to avoid multiple calls of items which are not in the first level of the loop) that $i doesn't seem to count properly for any reason while $workthrough works like a charm.
**Now, is it possible to have a continous counter in all the partialLoops? Also I really would like to know if maybe someone got a better approach to do what I want to do.**

If something looks strange or is unclear I will explain it of course. I appreciate any help!

Best Regards, .wired

Comment: Are you kidding! Why would you instantiate the model in your view, that's what the controller is for! you pass the model to the view from the corresponding action!

Comment: To me also the global smells and the partial in a partial too. I'll think about another way to do that.

Comment: And btw. the plural of child is children.

Comment: @ 1.: No, but I passed the items already to the partialLoop() and I also know this is not nice, but I didn't know how to pass another object to the loop (I'm still pretty new to ZF). @ 2.: Yep I also didn't like this approach which is the reason why I asked here =) @ 3.: I will correct it ;) Besides of this: Thank You for Your help, I honestly appreciate it :) I will look if I can figure out what You meant by Your answer below, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few bits of information which may help you:

- Using nested partials works but since partials clone the view, it can quickly become a performance problem and should better be avoided
- You can pass your rowset to the partial as an object which would enable you to call dependent rowsets `$view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model')`
- In your case it's probably better to loop yourself and use render() instead of partials.